# How to make VS-Code Flatpak to detect Docker Snap

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, flatpak, snap

In my conquest to make all my apps run from containers, I have, as expected, ran into some problems. I installed VS-Code as a Flatpak and installed the Docker plugin, but the plugin is not able to detect the docker binary because docker is actually running in a snap.

### STEPS TO REPLICATE:

```
snap install docker
flatpak install com.visualstudio.code
```

- open vscode
- install plugin:
  Name: Docker 
  Id: ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
  Description: Makes it easy to create, manage, and debug containerized applications.
  Version: 1.17.0
  Publisher: Microsoft
  VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
- click on docker icon

### EXPECTED RESULT:

All resource monitors work and docker is detected.

### ACTUAL RESULT:

Nothing works. Starting a terminal and executing `echo $PATH` gives: `/app/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin` which is not my actual path.

### THINGS I HAVE TRIED:

- `export PATH=$PARH:/snap/bin` but /snap/bin shows as empty in the integrated terminal
- `export PATH=$PARH:/snap/docker/current/bin` integrated terminal now works but the rest of the monitors and build options do not.
- setting the docker PATH in the plugin settings '/snap/docker/current/bin' but now gives: `Failed to connect. Is Docker installed and running? Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/docker.sock`
- giving permissions to the vscode flatpak like:

```
flatpak override --filesystem=host-os com.visualstudio.code 
flatpak override --filesystem=host com.visualstudio.code
flatpak override --filesystem=/snap/bin com.visualstudio.code
```

did not seem the be any difference